# Printed JPG image with mirrored output

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, jpeg

Hi Guys: i'm able to print with an SDk and the image is printing with correct size but the image is mirrored.

How can i fix this? what is the error from the below code?

```
 public bool PrintImage(string imgPath) {

        using (Bitmap img = new Bitmap(imgPath)) {

            IntPtr rawPtr = convertImageToRaw(img);
            return Api.SendImageData(portNumber, rawPtr, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
        }
    }



      private IntPtr convertImageToRaw(Bitmap bmp) {


        int width = bmp.Width;
        int height = bmp.Height;
        Bitmap targetBmp;
        Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(bmp);
        targetBmp = newBmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, newBmp.Width, newBmp.Height), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        BitmapData bmpData = targetBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, targetBmp.PixelFormat);
        int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmpData.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
        Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, rgbValues, 0, bytes);


        GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(rgbValues, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr result = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        newBmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);
        bmp.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\\Users\\Pictures\\images\\", "test123.jpg"));
        targetBmp.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\\Users\\Pictures\\images\\", "test1234.jpg"));
        newBmp.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\\Users\\Pictures\\images\\", "test1235.jpg"));
        newBmp.Dispose();


        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why are  you calling rotateflip?

Comment: @Andy: to understand whether any flip without my knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, your original photo contains EXIF metadata records. Among others, it can contain additional instructions how to process the image before being shown. Some apps/SDKs do respect that instructions, others silently ignore EXIF - this is why you can receive such thing as mirroring etc.

[EXIF orientation values](https://sirv.com/help/resources/rotate-photos-to-be-upright/)

> There are 8 possible EXIF orientation values, numbered 1 to 8.
>
> 1. 0 degrees – the correct orientation, no adjustment is required.
> 2. 0 degrees, mirrored – image has been flipped back-to-front.
> 3. 180 degrees – image is upside down.
> 4. 180 degrees, mirrored – image is upside down and flipped back-to-front.
> 5. 90 degrees – image is on its side.
> 6. 90 degrees, mirrored – image is on its side and flipped back-to-front.
> 7. 270 degrees – image is on its far side.
> 8. 270 degrees, mirrored – image is on its far side and flipped back-to-front.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by rotate108FlipX.

```
 img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
 IntPtr rawPtr = convertImageToRaw(img);
 return Api.SendImageData(portNumber, rawPtr, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
```